# NSCollectionView or NSTableView for a linear video implementation?

Tags: macos, nstableview, nscollectionview

I need some general advice.

I'd like to set up a horizontal view that consist of up to 4 media (video) tracks, along with a timeline indicator, not terribly dissimilar from FCP and other linear video editors.  It is very possible that some parts of the timeline will be sparsely populated (eg. with `NSNull` placeholders).

A see a few possible ways to do this:

1. one `NSCollectionView` of four rows and infinite columns.  Quite tricky to shuffle adds and deletes.
2. four `NSCollectionViews`, one for each row.  Infinite columns.  A little easier in some respects.
3. one `NSTableView` with four rows and infinite columns.  But  don't think table views like expansive columns.
4. some manner of a custom control

The timeline indicator *could* be implemented with an `NSRulerView`.  The underlying timeline grid consist of standardized units (ie. 30 seconds per "spot"), and media elements will be of 30s length.  (There is possibility of 10- or 15-second spots, but let's ignore that for now).

I've already implemented an `NSCollectionView` elsewhere in my app; it really isn't kludge-free in the case of a sparse matrix of info, and is really only designed for rectangularly presented data in the UI.  (Not to mention my seemingly impossible task of shutting off fade animations when the view is reloaded).

I eventually want to be able to drag-and-drop a media element to a video track and it will populate in-place.  The timeline will be backed to a CoreData store.

Any hints on where to start?